# Show fixed direction of a position vector

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vector-spaces, cross-product

I came across this question in preparation for my mid semester exam:

> Suppose that $m(t)$, where t is the parameter, $ t ∈ \mathbb{R}$, is a position vector with the
>   properties as follows: $$m(t) \times \frac{dm(t)}{dt} = 0$$ Proof that
>   this vector has a fixed direction.

I have no idea how to approach this question, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does that $\;\times\;$ there mean vectorial product? You also didn't say whether $\;m(t)\in\Bbb R^3\;$ or $\;m(t)\in\Bbb R^2\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, the vectorial product. Hmm... it does not say anything about $m(t)$, what was stated is only t is the parameter where $t∈\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Showing that $m''(t)=0$ ought to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1: Geometric Intuition**

For any vectors $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^3$, we have that $a\times b = 0$ only if either

- $a=0$ or $b=0$
- $a||b$ or $a||-b$

Here $a=m(t)$ and $b=m'(t)$. Then:

- If $m(t)=0$, then the direction never changes (the position is always zero)
- If $m'(t)=0$, then the tangent vector never changes (i.e. it always points in the same direction), hence the curve must be a straight line, aligned with $m'(t)$.
- If the $m$ and $m'$ are parallel (or anti-parallel) then the curve must again be a line since the position vector must always be aligned with the tangent vector (if the curve ever turned, $m$ and $m'$ would no longer be aligned).

Hence the line must be straight, and so the direction never changes.

---

**Method 2: Definition of Curvature**

By definition, the curvature of a space curve can be written:
$$
\kappa = \frac{|| T(t) \times T'(t) ||}{|| T'(t) ||^3}
$$
where $T(t)=m'(t)$. But, it is given that $T(t) \times T'(t) = 0$.

Hence, $\kappa=0$. Thus the curve must be straight, because any bending (i.e. change in direction) would give it non-zero curvature.

(Note: because the unit normal is given by $N(t)=T'(t)/||T'(t)||=m''(t)/||m''(t)$ when we parametrize by arclength, this is equivalent to the comment above suggesting to show that $m''(t)=0$.
See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1164398/why-is-the-derivative-of-a-vector-orthogonal-to-the-vector-itself). And yes, I know its the same as part 3 of method 1 too.)