# Prove that if $r(t)\times \frac{dr(t)}{dt}=0$, then $r(t)$ has a fixed direction.

Tags: calculus, analysis, vectors, parametric

Let $r(t)$, where $t$ is a parameter $(t ∈R)$, be a position vector such that $r(t)\times \frac{dr(t)}{dt}=0$

I am asked to show that r(t) has a ﬁxed direction.
A hint says: Let $r(t) = f(t)\hat e(t)$ where $\hat e(t)$ is a unit vector).

Could someone tell me how to use the hint? May I ask for a proof?

EDIT: I did some searching and found this question [Show fixed direction of a position vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2184737/show-fixed-direction-of-a-position-vector)
But I cannot understand the answer. Could someone please use the hint to explicitly show that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you consider using the Frenet-Serret equations?

Comment: Do you know the vectorial product of two vectors is a vector perpendicular to both original vectors? And thus, if the vect. product of two vectors is zero that means both vectors are parallel *or else* one of them is zero...and thus we're basically done?

Comment: @MikhailKatz Sorry I have not learn about that. If it is relevant, could you please tell me how to consider about it?

Comment: @DonAntonio I think it makes sense geometrically, but here I need a proof using the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $r(t)=f(t)ê (t)$ then

$$ \frac{d \vec r}{dt} = f'(t)ê (t) + f(t)\frac{dê (t)}{dt} $$

$$ \vec r \times \frac{d \vec r}{dt} = \vec r \times f'(t)ê (t) + \vec r \times f(t)\frac{dê (t)}{dt} = \vec r \times f(t)\frac{dê (t)}{dt} = 0$$

Thus $\frac{dê (t)}{dt} = 0$ or  $\vec r$ is parallel to $\frac{dê (t)}{dt}$

But $\vec r$ is perpendicular to $\frac{dê (t)}{dt}$ because of the property - "[A vector of constant magnitude is perpendicular to it's derivative.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1164398/why-is-the-derivative-of-a-vector-orthogonal-to-the-vector-itself)"

Therefore, $\frac{dê (t)}{dt} = 0$ i.e. there is no change in the direction vector.

Comment: May I ask how can we formally conclude that $\overrightarrow r\times f'(t)\hat e(t)=0$?

Comment: Why is $$ \vec r \times f'(t)ê (t) + \vec r \times f(t)\frac{dê (t)}{dt} = \vec r \times f(t)\frac{dê (t)}{dt}$$ true? Meaning, why $\;r\times f'\hat e=0\;$ ?

Comment: @Y.X. $\vec r$ and $\hat e(t)$ are parallel from the assumption $\vec r = f(t) \hat e(t)$. Thus their cross product is zero.

Comment: @TimTheEnchanter But may I ask why can we assume it? That is, is that true that for all vector-valued function, we are able to express it in this form? How can I see this?

Comment: @Y.X. We can represent any vector in terms of it's magnitude and direction. All the expression $\vec r = f(t) \hat e(t)$ does is say that we have a time dependant vector $\vec r$ (denoting t by time) , whose magnitude is time dependant as $f(t)$ and its direction is time dependant as $\hat e(t)$

Comment: @Y.X. It looks like it is going to be a little hard to avoid some basic geometry *completely* , as you seem to want.

Comment: @Y.X. If you want to avoid geometry completely, you can call $\vec r$ an n-tuple and you can say the statement $\vec r = f(t) \hat e(t)$ is just splitting the n-tuple into a scalar f(t) and a normalised n-tuple $\hat e(t)$. Its a way of looking at it, just not a particularly appealing one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I get it.

Comment: May I ask why we have$\frac{d\hat e(t)}{dt}=0$ instead of $r$ is  parallel to $\frac{d\hat e(t)}{dt}$?

Comment: $\frac{d\hat e(t)}{dt}=0$ represents the tangent vector, and is hence always perpendicular to $\hat e(t)$ and hence $\vec r$

Comment: Do you mean that it is the normal vector? Since I think the tangent vector is always parallel to the orginal vetor instead of perpendicular.

Comment: @Y.X. No $\frac{d\hat e(t)}{dt}$ is the tangent vector and the normal vector is $\hat e(t)$. Think of it this way. The vector $\hat e(t)$ occupies the unit sphere centred at origin. Clearly then the normal is actually $\hat e(t)$ and the tangent vector $\frac{d\hat e(t)}{dt}$ is perpendicular to $\hat e(t)$ ( from the properties of a sphere).

Comment: @PropositionX I've edited the answer to explain why $\frac{dê (t)}{dt} = 0$ instead of $\vec r$ is parallel to $\frac{dê (t)}{dt}$. No need to be confused thinking about geometrical interpretation in terms of tangent or normal..

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. A counterexample:

$$ r(t) = \begin{cases} (0,t^2) & \text{for } t\le 0 \\ (t^2,0) & \text{for } t> 0 \end{cases} $$

If you have the additional assumption that $r(t)\ne 0$, then your property holds, and something like Tim the Enchanter's proof should work.