# Can I have an example of arc length parameterization of a curve?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

In the construction of the Frenet-Serret triad along a curve in $\mathbb R^3$ arc length parameterization of the tangent vector ensures [orthogonal](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3499297/276181) orientation of the curvature vector by making the norm of the tangent vector unitary. This is explained beautifully at [this point of this lecture](https://youtu.be/NKlfCLsFzUY?t=69) by Claudio Arezzo.

The example of a logarithmic exponential is elaborated on; however, the "trivial" ending is left out as mechanical - and it is. However, I wanted to ask for its completion, and then I figured I might as well ask myself. So I'm posting this as a Q&A for future reference, and in case it helps someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $$\begin{cases}x=e^{at}\cos t,\\y=e^{at}\sin t\end{cases}$$
the arc length is 
$$s=\int_{-\infty}^t e^{at}\sqrt{(a\cos t-\sin t)^2+(a\sin t+\cos t)^2}dt=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+1}\,e^{at}}{a}.$$

So,

$$\begin{cases}x=\dfrac{as}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\cos\dfrac{\log\dfrac{as}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}}a,\\y=\dfrac{as}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\sin\dfrac{\log\dfrac{as}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}}a\end{cases}$$

is the arc length parameterization.

Comment: Thank you! Can you include the steps from $s$ to the final parameterization? The $\log(\cdot)$ indicates that you are using the inverse of $s$ to replace $t$ in the first set of equations, and since there is a $e^{\log(\cdot)}$ in the $a^{at}$ we end up with just the inverse ($e$ "cancels" $\log)$... Also, you are integrating from $-\infty$ whereas on my post it is from $0.$  In addition, you have left the tangent implied, but - just out of curiosity - considering all there is no contradiction between posts, is there?

Comment: @Mathstunned: integration from $-\infty$ is for convenience, it simplifies the equations but is harmless. What do you mean by "tangent implied" ?

Comment: I mean that your final equations parametrize the curve by arc length, which is just perfect. Yet, the final step would be to get the derivatives of $x$ and $y$ to generate the tangent vector to the curve at each point, which - by construction - would have norm $1.$ I am planning on accepting your answer, but I would want to make sure - for my own curiosity - that there is no contradiction with what I wrote...

Answer (score 0):

The parameterized spiral used as an example is

$$
 \begin{align}
\alpha(t) &= \left (e^{-0.2t} \cos(t),e^{-0.2t}\sin(t)\right)
 \end{align}
$$

and the function $s(t)$

$$\begin{align}I \to \mathbb R\\
s(t) =\int_{t_o}^t \vert \alpha'(u)\vert du
\end{align}$$

corresponds to the length of the curve from $t_o$ to $t,$ which in the example under consideration is

$$ \begin{align}s(t) &=\int_0^t \vert \left (e^{-0.2t} \cos(t),e^{-0.2t}\sin(t)\right) \vert dt\\&=\small \int_0^t \sqrt{ (-0.2)^2e^{-0.2t} \cos^2(t)+e^{-0.2t} \sin^2(t)+(-0.2)^2e^{-0.2t}\sin^2(t)+e^{-0.2t} \cos^2(t)} dt\\
&=\frac{e^{-0.2t}-1}{-0.2}\sqrt{(-0.2)^2+1}
 \end{align}$$

Its inverse is

$$\varphi(g)=s^{-1}(g)=-5 \log(-0.196116 (g - 5.09902))$$

And the tangent to the curve parameterized by the arc length, i.e. $\beta(g)=\alpha\circ\varphi=\alpha(\varphi(g))$:

$$\begin{align}
&\\\beta'(g)&=\alpha'\left( \varphi(g)\right)\varphi'(g)\\
&=\small{ (0.98058\sin(5\ln(-0.196116 (x - 5.09902))) - 0.196116\cos(5\ln(-0.196116 (g - 5.09902))),} \\ &\small{0.196116\sin(5\ln(-0.196116 (g - 5.09902))) + 0.98058\cos(5\ln(-0.196116 (g - 5.09902))))}
\end{align}$$

yielding unitary tangent vectors to each point on the curve:

[image]